# Install all packages in root and switch to a non-root user or use `gosu` or `sudo` directly in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, security, pip

To Follow the best practices on Docker images, we have to run the container as a non-root user (as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user)).

One of the ideas is to add something similar to the following lines:

```
ARG USERNAME=user
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=1000

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
USER $USERNAME
```

However the need of installing packages makes the use of the `root` user or usage with `sudo` or `gosu` mandatory. Also, going back in forth and changing users from root and container user isn't really advised.

So I'm asking myself several questions reagrding security best practices:

- Should we install all the packages in root on the Dockerfile and move on to the user created when all things are updated, with the risk of moving back and forth for example to use pip with the non-root user or even `cargo` for Rust ?
- Is it valuable to use `gosu` (or even `sudo` and adding the user to the sudoers)? Doesn't that mean that the created user will be a sudoer and have root privileges anyway?
- Does the root should still be available inside the docker as a privileged user?

Comment: The best practice says **to run** the container as a non-root user, not **to create** it.

Comment: @Pino AFAIU the question is about processes inside the containers. `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @Pino It's not about creation, some actions requires root privileges, and it's using it and having a non-root user when the container runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we install all the packages in root on the Dockerfile and move on to the user created when all things are updated

Yes.  Note that some OS tools like the Debian APT package manager *require* running as root.

I'd consider it reasonable to build the application as root and switch only to a non-root `USER` at the very end of the Dockerfile.

> Is it valuable to use `gosu` (or even `sudo` and adding the user to the sudoers)?

No.  The "pattern" I see in SO questions generally involves assigning an easily-guessable fixed password to the user that's readily visible in source control and `docker history`, and then gives that user unrestricted `sudo` permissions.  This might protect against some classes of accidents, but an actual attacker will figure out pretty quickly that they just need to prefix their commands with `sudo`.

You probably shouldn't install `sudo` at all.  Switching `USER` as needed (even if it's multiple times) is easier and doesn't require additional setup.

> Does the root should still be available inside the docker as a privileged user?

Practically speaking, "root" is defined as the user whose user ID is 0.  You can't prevent `docker run -u 0` or `docker exec -u 0`, even if you delete the `root` entry from `/etc/passwd`.  I wouldn't try to disable this.

> Is it valuable to use `gosu` (revisited)?

There's a common pattern of using an image's `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script that does some first-time setup, and then uses Bourne shell `exec "$@"` to switch to the main `CMD`.  I see the very occasional image where this first-time setup *must* be done as root, but you don't want the main process to be as root.  In this specific case, it's useful to use `gosu` to "step down" to an unprivileged user.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

if [ "$(id -u)" != 0 ]; then
  echo 'container must start as root' >&2
  exit 1
fi

chown user /foo  # or something else that must be root

exec gosu user "$@"
```

Finally: I'd argue against passing the user name or numeric IDs as Dockerfile `ARG`.  Pick a fixed name for the user, and let **useradd**(8) pick the numeric uid on its own.  You don't generally want to build an image that's specific to a specific host user ID.  On the reverse side, there's no specific requirement that a user "exist", and you can almost always `docker run -u $(id -u)` to assume the host user's numeric uid when you run the container without doing further setup.